# Semaphore timeout mechanism in C#

Tags: c#, timeout, semaphore

Does anyone know how .NET handles a timeout on a call to `Semaphore.WaitOne(timeout)`?

I'd expect a `TimeoutException`, but the MSDN documentation doesn't list this in the list of expected exceptions, and I can't seem to find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method will return `false` if it times out, and `true` if it returns a signal:

```
if (mySemaphore.WaitOne(1000))
{
    // signal received
}
else
{
    // wait timed out
}
```